# Why can I see multiple desktops on my laptop display?

Tags: display, screen

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (dual-boot with Windows 7) and the image below shows the current display (6 multiple screens).

[image]

Anyone know how to rectify this?

Step-by-step instruction is highly appreciated, I'm a newbie!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed drivers for your display? Driver software would probably work. To install them, you will need to access the laptop manufacturer's website. Through the manufacturer's website, you will be able to locate driver software, then download the correct drivers for **Linux**. Ubuntu will most-likely not be an option.